# family tree sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on Family tree application in asp.net with sql server 2008.

My main table is like this:-

```
ID int PK
Name Varchar(50)
MotherID int
FatherID int

ID  MotherID FatherID   Name

1   NULL    NULL    My Grand Father

2   NULL    NULL    My Grand Mother

3   someid  someid  My Mother

4   2   1   My Father

5   3   4   Me

6   someid  someid  My wife

7   3   4   My Brother

8   6   5   My son.
```

I am looking for output like this

```
ID  MotherID    FatherID    Name        Level

1   someid  someid  grandfather 0


2   someid  someid  Father      1

3   someid  someid  Me      2


4   someid  someid  Brother     2

5   someid  someid  My Son      3
```

Thanks in advance.
Kashmir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH FamilyCTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      *, 
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(50)) AS FatherName,  
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(50)) AS MotherName, 0 AS Level
    FROM @FamilyTree
    WHERE FatherID IS NULL 
      AND MotherID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      f.ID, 
      f.Name AS ParentName, 
      f.MotherID, 
      f.FatherID, 
      c.Name AS FatherName, 
      c2.Name AS MotherName, 
      Level + 1
    FROM @FamilyTree AS F
    INNER JOIN FamilyCTE c ON F.FatherID = c.ID
    INNER JOIN @FamilyTree c2 ON f.MotherID = c2.ID
)

SELECT * FROM FamilyCTE
```

### [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84004/family-tree-sql-query)

If want to get the exact output like what you posted in your question just ignore the `FatherName` and `MotherName` and limit the selection in the `SELECT * FROM FamilyCTE` to the columns you want to select, with a starting grand father in the anchor query using `WHERE ID = 1` for example. As in the following demo:

### [DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84006/family-tree-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you very much Mahmoud Gamal!!! I need to find the full family tree of a user who is a grandson. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @KashmirSingh - Its my pleasure.

Comment: The above answer is perfect one. But I want a family tree of user who is son so that he can see his family tree from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.ID, t1.MotherID, 
t1.FatherID,
t1.name, 
t2.Name,
Level
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.FatherID =t2.FatherID
```

Comment: No, I am looking something like family tree output with Common Table Expression.